# How do I show/hide text when click radio button in Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have 2 radio buttons that select units (cm/ft). 
If I select "cm", text would be change to cm.

How do I show/hide text when click radio button in Bootstrap

This is my example code here

https://jsfiddle.net/A8Znx/42

```
<style>
body {
    padding:50px;
}
.btn-select { border:1px solid #333 }
.btn-select.active { background:#999}
</style>

<div class="unit done">
  <input type="text" id="" name="" class="input1" value="" style="width:230px">
  <em>cm</em>
</div>

<div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-select active">  
    <input type="radio" name="wrist" id="wrist1" autocomplete="off" checked /> cm  
  </label>

  <label class="btn btn-select">
    <input type="radio" name="wrist" id="wrist2" autocomplete="off" /> in
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you use jQuery?

Comment: I would almost argue to use the bootstrap input-groups and put the options on the end of the text box, and get rid of the text display all together.  Use the selected radio as the display.  https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/input-group/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap doesn't do custom DOM manipulation like that. You need to employ some basic jQuery:

```
<span class="unit done">
  <input type="text" id="" name="" class="input1" value="" style="width:230px">
  <em>cm</em>
  <em style="display: none;">in</em>
</span>

<div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle unit-toggler pull-right" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-select cm-unit active">  
    <input type="radio" name="wrist" id="wrist1" autocomplete="off" checked /> cm  
  </label>

  <label class="btn btn-select">
    <input type="radio" name="wrist" id="wrist2" autocomplete="off" /> in
  </label>
</div>


<script>
$('.unit-toggler input').change(function() {
  $('.unit em').toggle();
});
</script>
```

**[Demo fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/A8Znx/47/)**

Comment: Oh if I have multi radio groups, what should I need to do ? Because the problem is this change the text all together same time.

Comment: You'll have to encapsulate your markup somehow (class, ID, index) and target elements inside that grouping with whatever selector makes sense.

Comment: Get familiar with jQuery element selectors and the world is your oyster.

Answer (score 1):

Please include jQuery script first then use this code

```
<script src = "js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script> //your jquery version

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('input[name=wrist]').on('change', function() {
         var _sel = $(this);
         $('span.unit').find('em').text(_sel.parent().text());
    })
});
</script>
```

**[Demo fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/A8Znx/49/)**

Comment: One can safely assume that almost any Bootstrap site will have jQuery loaded.